# Visual Studio for Mac is just Xamarin / MonoDevelop ReBranded (?)

Tags: macos, visual-studio, ide

Is Visual Studio for Mac the full thing, or just a re-brand of MonoDevelop/Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio for Mac IS Xamarin Studio.

If you go to [Xamarin Studio's official download page](https://www.xamarin.com/download), you will see that its call to action button is "Download Visual Studio for Mac".